# Pluralizing the noun support

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it ever okay to pluralize the noun "support"? When talking about several support systems, for example, is it okay to say that people "need supports"? If not, why not? Thank you!

Comment: It is possible, but the situations in which this occurs should be rare. Your example gives me too little context to decide whether it is proper. In general, it is not okay to use *supports* to replace *support systems* except in jargon or very informal texts, I would say.

Comment: My feeling is that the only place where it is appropriate would be actual _physical_ supports, in buildings for example.

Comment: _Most of the supports for the bridge are in good shape, but a few of them need work._  But metaphorical supports are subject to different constraints. E.g, they're definitely not countable because they're so vague and systemic that one never knows where the boundaries are. Like counting clouds in a cloudy sky.

Answer (score 2):

The word *support* can be a noun, verb or adjective. The adjective usage is never pluralized:

> This support system is weak.

The verb usage can be pluralized depending on the subject:

> I can support your weight.
>
> That pylon supports the entire base.

The noun usage can be pluralized but only when it describes "[something that serves as a foundation, prop, brace, or stay](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/support)":

> The supports for this building were completed yesterday.
>
> My spouse is behind on child support.
>
> If your computer is broken, call tech support.

In your particular example, it is impossible to tell if you are referring to supports as in foundations or braces. The easy test is to refer to a specific number of supports:

> John needs 3 supports.

This obviously makes no sense when referring to *tech* support but does when referring to foundations or braces:

> John needs 3 tech supports.
>
> John needs 3 supports to finish the building.

Comment: I apologize for not being very clear. When I ask about "support" as a noun, I mean various ways to help a family in need. If a family is offered (for example) counseling, anger management tools, and ways to cope, can these be lumped together as supports plural? Or should support in this case remain singular because it indicates something somewhat nebulous? (I agree that in building supportS is sometimes indicated, but it doesn't sound correct to me in my example.) Thank you!

Comment: In that case it will always be singular. If you want to be clear there are more than one you would say something like, "There are three types of support."

Comment: Can you explain why it should always be singular? I need to be able to describe why supportS is wrong to the person who thinks it is okay. Thanks again!

Comment: For the same reason you wouldn't say "a family needs 3 supports." See the "tech support" example in my answer.

Comment: You might find the term *mass noun* useful. Mass nouns are always singular ("The *furniture* ***is*** wooden") but can sometimes be pluralised, when different types can be identified ("There are three different *rices* growing in that field"). Pluralisation doesn't work in all cases, and I would suggest that *support* is one of them.