# Which one is correct? 'Tools have no supports for ...' or 'Tools has no supports for ...'

Tags: grammar

I want to know which usage is correct:
`Software tools have no supports for ...` or `Software tools has no supports for ...`?

And why?

Comment: This is a simple singular/plural issue.  "Has" is used with singular, "have" with plural.  "Tools" is plural.  "Tool" is singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Software tools have no support for`. Because `Software tools` is plural, you need `have` instead of `has`. On the other hand, `support` is usually an uncountable noun, and therefore is never plural, except in the case of ["something that serves as a foundation, prop, brace, or stay"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/129923/45467)

Comment: Loren, answering questions that are poorly posed is frowned upon here.